# To detect the first run of Application

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults

I want to show a help overlay when a user runs my application for the first time.

To do this, I'm using the following code in`didFinishLaunching`:

```
if(![[[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryRepresentation] allKeys] containsObject:@"IPHONEFIRSTRUN"])
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setBool:TRUE forKey:@"IPHONEFIRSTRUN"];
```

In the view controller, I have:

```
if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]boolForKey:@"IPHONEFIRSTRUN"]==TRUE) {
    [self HelpOverlayIphone];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setBool:FALSE forKey:@"IPHONEFIRSTRUN"];
}
```

However, it shows the overlay on the second use as well. How can I fix this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Just an observation but your key is IPADFIRSTRUN in the first example and IPHONEFIRSTRUN in the second. Is this intentional?

Comment: The other thing I would check into (not that it will fix the problem you are seeing) is the fact that boolForKey already returns a bool so checking that bool to see if it's true is just silly.

Comment: sorry for the typo error,first one is also @"IPHONEFIRSTRUN",But it is not working

Comment: I might try `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize]` after each `setBool` to make sure your setting is getting saved.

Comment: @rob:  I swear I did not read your response before I re-wrote my answer...

Comment: @KendallHelmstetterGelner No problem. As long as we solve the OP's question. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your logic is overly complex.  You are setting permanently a user default to indicate something happening one time.  Instead, in the view controller see if the value is not set, if it is do your action and set the variable so that the code is NOT run again:

```
if ( ! [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]boolForKey:@"IPHONEFIRSTRUNCOMPLETE"] ) {
        [self HelpOverlayIphone];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setBool:YES forKey:@"IPHONEFIRSTRUNCOMPLETE"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

Take out all the code in the app delegate.

Also it's very likely your original code is not working because you are stopping the app from XCode. If you don't use `synchronize` user default changes will not be saved in that case (normal quitting of the app does eventually save the changes permanently).

Comment: That would definitely be a problem.

Comment: @MisVar: Probably because my original answer pointed out a misspelling that the poster corrected.  My new answer should satiate the rabid downvoter.

Answer (score 0):

Have you registered the defaults you are using at the start of the program? I would suggest rereading the apple documentation for NSUserDefaults [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

You need to first make a call to

```
- (void)registerDefaults:(NSDictionary *)dictionary
```

which will only set the key if it doesn't already exist. Then check the key for falseness on the the first run and set it at this point.

My guess is the reason your code isn't working is because the dictionary is never actually being saved in any sort of persistent way.

Answer (score 0):

I have this function which fires when the app fires up- it's always been reliable. I have a uniqueNameOfApp which is just some random hash so that it doesn't collide with other apps.

```
-(void)loadSettings {
NSMutableDictionary *sttngs = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] 
objectForKey:uniqueNameOfApp];

    if(sttngs != nil) {
    [userSettings addEntriesFromDictionary:sttngs];
    } else {
    _appFiredForFirstTime = YES;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your saved user defaults cannot be seen by other apps, so there's no worry of a collision...